# Codename One - Integer / Date exception

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a picker on my Main form. I need to go to another form and when I go back to Main I want the picker to show the same value as before. In order to do that, I wanted to save the value of the picker into an static Date variable, but when I run the code I get a "Integer cannot be cast to Date" exception. I am attaching a picture of a try I did assigning the value to an auxiliar Date variable. I get the same error:

[image]

Comment: Please add the code where you set the value to the picker itself. Also provide the stack message from the console in questions such as this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you invoked `setDate` on the picker and not some other method such as `setTime` that is meant for a time picker.

Notice that date/time & date-time pickers use different data types.

Comment: It was a Time picker. What I decided to do was to save the text in the picker using getText(), and then extract the first 2 (hour) and last 2 (minutes) characters from the string. Then, when I went back to the initial form and wanted to show the time, I invoke setTime(hour,minute)

Comment: No. Use `getTime` which returns an int that represents minutes since midnight which is far more convenient than `Date`.